# ASP.NET how to add to data to gridview from button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested gridview. On the top-level grid, I have a button that should call a stored procedure and and put that data into the nested gridview.

Here is my ASPX page code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button Text="Expand" runat="server" OnClick="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="135px" DataField="Label" HeaderText="Label" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="IDs" HeaderText="IDs" />

                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="${0:###,###,###.00}" DataField="Total" HeaderText=Total" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Label" HeaderText="Label" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="${0:###,###,###.00}" DataField="Total20" HeaderText="Total20" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="${0:###,###,###.00}" DataField="Total1" HeaderText="Total1" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="{0:P1}"  DataField="Average_Fee_PCT" HeaderText="Average Fee" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

Here is my C# code

```
protected void Select(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ID = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;

            Response.Write("<script>console.log('ID...." + ID + "');</script>");
            
        GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;          
        gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("exec ReturnDataSingle '" + ID + "', '"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"));
        gvOrders.DataBind();


}
```

Here is the error message I am getting

> 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found

Can someone help me figure out how I would be able to add the stored procedure data to the gvOrders gridview based off that button click?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the `sender` object into the button that was clicked, followed by this, get the `NamingContainer` of the button and in the row (`GridViewRow`) look for the GridView control, the next part is to load the data:

```
protected void Select(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn= (Button)sender;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

    GridView GridChild = ((GridView)row.FindControl("gvOrders"));

    // Fill GridView
    GridChild.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("exec ReturnDataSingle '" + ID + "', '"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"));
    GridChild.DataBind();
}
```

The problem was that the `Row` property is applicable on a `GridViewRowEventArgs` object, normally it is handled in the `RowDataBound` event but you need to fire the event through Click, therefore you are forced to use `EventArgs` object